# Titlesec chapter headings wrapped over two lines

Tags: titlesec

I'm using titlesec to produce chapter headings with this code:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\huge\sc}
{\sc\filright\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
{0ex}
{\titlerule
\vspace{0ex}%
\filleft}
[\vspace{0ex}]
```

Now it works fine, but I'd like to force it to wrap lines to only the right say two-thirds of the line. This is to make it look nicer when I have a long title.

When I force a linebreak, it works fine `\chapter{Test with a title that is\\too long for one line}`, but then I have two problems. Firstly, the fancyhdr titles end up being over two lines. Secondly, the gap between the lines is too long. Any suggestions?

[image: Short title]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a complete example. This is much more useful than a mere fragment. `\sc` is obsolete for 20+ years in LaTeX and ought not be used, just like all the other long-deprecated two letter font switches. Use `\scshape` instead.

Comment: The optional argument for sectional divisions can be used to override the heading in headers and the contents e.g. `\chapter[Text for headers and contents]{Text for body of document}`. Similarly for `\section` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the title in a `minipage`. The spacing cannot be helped unless you post the code responsible. I've added spacing to prevent the title actually hanging from the rule by the tops of its letters.

Note that `\bfseries` will be effective only if you choose a non-default font which features bold small-caps. In any case, `\sc` should not be used in LaTeX 2e. Use `\scshape` instead. Otherwise, `\bfseries` will have no effect even if you do choose a non-default font which features bold small-caps.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\huge\scshape}% note that \bfseries has no effect with the default fonts
{\filright\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
{0ex}
{\titlerule
  \vspace{1ex}%
  \filleft\begin{minipage}{.67\textwidth}}
[\end{minipage}]
\begin{document}

Some text.

\chapter{Bulbous Brandishes Burnish Bournemouth Busily}

Some more.

\chapter{Aardvark Antics Anticipate Angelic Adventures After Arctic Advance}

Yet further stuff.

\end{document}
```

[image: minipage titles]

It is almost certainly preferable, from an aesthetic standpoint, to break the lines at a sensible place manually, possibly abbreviating the title as well for the headers:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\huge\scshape}% note that \bfseries has no effect with the default fonts
{\filright\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
{0ex}
{\titlerule
  \vspace{1ex}%
  \filleft}
\begin{document}

Some text.

\chapter[Bulbous Brandishes Burnish Bournemouth Busily]{Bulbous\\ Brandishes Burnish\\Bournemouth Busily}

Some more.

\chapter[Aardvark Antics Anticipate Angelic Adventures]{Aardvark Antics\\Anticipate Angelic\\Adventures After\\Arctic Advance}

Yet further stuff.

\newpage And more.

\end{document}
```

[image: aardvarks are amazing]