# Chapter title with particular style and font size

Tags: sectioning, chapters, fontsize

I want my chapter title to be like this

[image]

here is my latex code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

 \chapter{INTRODUCTION}

 \end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

I also need to change the font size of the chapter title to 14 pt. Any help?

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277533/4778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the original definition of `\@makechapterhead` from `report.cls`:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

The above macro sets the header what you use `\chapter`. Let's change it to match your output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \large\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 10\p@
        \rule[.5ex]{\textwidth}{.4pt}%
        \vskip 10\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \large \bfseries \MakeUppercase{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

`\large` under the `12pt` document class option results in a `14pt` font. You can add your font selection within the definition.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage{microtype}
 \SetTracking[no ligatures={f}]{encoding=*}{100}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\bfseries\Large\lsstyle\SetTracking[no ligatures = {f}]{encoding = *}{50}\filleft}
 {\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\enspace\thechapter}
 {2ex}
 {\titlerule[1pt]\vspace{2ex}\MakeUppercase}%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-60pt}{10ex}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]